# Export-Csv from global to local variable

Tags: csv, powershell-2.0, export-to-csv

I'm trying to store the output of the script in the `foreach` loop in a local variable and then export it to CSV on my local system from remote sessions:

```psh
$cred = Get-Credential domain\username
$TargetSession = Get-Content C:\test\computers.txt

foreach ($Computer in $TargetSession) {
    $Session = New-PSSession $Computer -Credential $cred
    $result = Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ArgumentList $computer -ScriptBlock {
        $Database = "secaudit"

        #SMTP Relay Server
        $SMTPServer = "smtp.mail.net"
        $SqlQuery = "xp_fixeddrives"
        $SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
        $SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=$computer;Initial Catalog=$Database;Integrated Security = True"
        $SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
        $SqlCmd.CommandText = $SqlQuery
        $SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
        $SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
        $SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd
        $DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
        $nRecs = $SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
        $nRecs | Out-Null
        $objTable = $DataSet.Tables[0]
    } 

    $final = Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock {
        $result
    } | Export-Csv -Path c:\test\output_space.csv -NoTypeInformation

    Remove-PSSession -Session $Session
}
```

but I'm getting the following error:

```
Export-Csv : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'InputObject' because it is null.
At C:\test\drivespace_mail.ps1:33 char:75
+ $final= Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock{$result}| Export-Csv <<<<  -path c:\test\output_space.csv -NoTypeInformation
   + CategoryInfo : InvalidData: (:) [Export-Csv],ParameterBindingValidationException
   + FullyQualifiedErrorId ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands`.ExportCsvCommand
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables inside scriptblocks are in a different scope than the ones outside the scriptblock, so if you have code like this:

```
$foo = 'something'
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { $foo }
```

you have two different variables `$foo` with the one inside the scripblock being empty, because it was never initilized.

You can use variables from the outer scope inside a scriptblock either by passing them into the scriptblock as arguments:

```psh
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {
  Param($foo)
  $foo
} -ArgumentList $foo
```

or via the `using:` [scope modifier](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847849.aspx):

```psh
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { $using:foo }
```

However, your first `Invoke-Command` never outputs/returns anything (all output is assigned to variables and thus lost when the invocation returns). Because nothing gets assigned to `$result` you'll get the same error even if you make the variable accessible in the second scriptblock.

Also, your double command invocation is needlessly complicated. Simply use a pipeline like this:

```psh
Get-Content 'C:\test\computers.txt' | ForEach-Object {
    Invoke-Command -Computer $_ -ScriptBlock {
        Param($computer)
        $Database = 'secaudit'
        ...
        $DataSet.Tables[0]
    } -ArgumentList $_ -Credential $cred
} | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\test\output_space.csv' -NoType
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , I tried the code which you have give and it worked like a jem...could you please let me know how can i export the output of that query to a local sqlserver table instead of a CSV.

Comment: I tried the below code to export the data from CSV to sql table, is there any way to directly put the output in the sql table on the local machine ??                                                                                                    $query = @"
BULK INSERT [Test1].[dbo].[table] FROM 'C:\test\output_space.csv' WITH (FIRSTROW = 2, 

FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', ROWTERMINATOR = '\n')
"@
sqlcmd -S "sqlserver" -E -Q $query

Comment: What does that have to do with your question? If you have a new or followup question: please post a new question.